# Service Bus for Windows Java?

Tags: java, servicebus

We are evaluating Service Bus for Windows Server 1.0 for use as an on-site Service Bus and are really liking how easy it is to install, configure, manage, etc, and developing .NET applications that take advantage of it are also quite easy.

Part of the company uses Java though and we would like to be able to leverage any Service Bus implementation from both code bases. Since there is a lot of feature parity between Service Bus for Windows and the Azure Service Bus, can we use the Azure SDK for Java to interact with our local service bus?

I have found several code samples for the Java SDK, but they are all geared towards the Azure bus, so I'm not quite sure what values to provide when attempting to connect.

For instance, everything revolves around creating a `ServiceBusContract` instance, which takes a `Configuration` instance created by the `ServiceBusConfiguration.configureWithWrapAuthentication` or `ServiceBusConfiguration.configureWithConnectionString` methods.

In the case of the `.condifureWithWrapAuthentication` method, what should I be passing in for the `serviceBusRootUri` (examples say to use '.servicebus.Windows.net'; this obviously won't work locally) and `wrapRootUri` (examples say to use '-sb.accesscontrol.windows.net/WRAPv0.9'; again, this won't work locally) parameters? I did stumble across [this post](http://www.rqgg.net/topic/myrkv-azure-service-bus-and-java.html) that says the JavaDocs give more information that you think, including local configuration, but I've read it top to bottom about 6 times and don't see anything local about it.

Does anyone know of or have a sample that shows how to access a local Service Bus using Java and the v0.4.2 SDK?

Comment: Based on the FAQ, I am intrigued on why this question was closed (especially since this question seems to be similar to `software tools commonly used by programmers` and `practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession`).

Comment: Same here; I posted that as a response to the question on the SO Meta boards topic "Is it too easy to close a question" giving my 2-cents based on this question being closed. If i was asking which was better (tabs vs. spaces), then I could understand. _sigh_

Comment: Why on Earth is this question closed???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab a connection string for the namespaces for server (using [this command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj248758%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) in Service Bus Powershell). That should show you the serviceBusRootUri for your namespaces.

**Edit:** Server does not support ACS -- it only supports SaS and Windows Authentication. I don't believe the Java SDK supports those natively, so I don't believe it would fit your need.

Comment: Ok, that would make sense. I guess I was confused by the examples that started with '.' which made me believe that the namespace was going to be prepended to the address, which wouldn't resolve.

Comment: I tried as you suggested (using the STS Endpoint address for the wrapRootUri parameter) and I get an **UnknownHostException** and the value it gives me is the namespace concatenated to the `wrapRootUri` value (ie - ServiceBusDefaultNamespace**https**). I removed the schema from the URI and passed in an empty string for the namespace and now I get back a `PKIX path building failed` error for the self-signed certificate that was generated when the Service Bus farm was created.

Comment: I am working on finding out the correct `wrapRootUri` right now. I will let you know when I find it out! It won't appear in the connection string you get when you run that command.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like my only use case for Java would be to use HTTP/REST. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Why was my question closed as "off topic"?? I am asking about using the Windows Azure for **JAVA** SDK, specifically which methods to use to establish a connection and what values to use as parameters, to access a local Service Bus install. If this is suddenly considered "off topic" for a programming board, then SO is going down hill. Thanks at least to @TheDude for helping me move forward and discover it's not possible with the SDK.